# How to create the video gallery in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to create video gallery for my forum but did not get any idea and searched the net but got only image gallery examples with free source code but  video gallery applications are payable. Can anyone give the idea for creating video gallery using flex?

**For Example:**

First Shows the set of thumbnail image in component when user click the thumbnail image, that time need to show the popup window with related video.

Below I gave the sample link:

```
     http://example.procontent.net/Carousel/carousel_flex.html
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty nebulous question.

You could get quite a ways towards a solution by using [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to generate clips of your videos. Then link to these using your carousel and playback in a popup. Your playback could be streamed from [Red5](https://code.google.com/p/red5/) (or similar).

Comment: Thanks for your response but did not get any idea from your reply can you please explanation in detail.FMS is using to streaming.

Comment: 1. get a list of videos. 2. use FFMPEG to generate still image from each. 3. use flex to display these images. 4. use flex 'videoplayer' control to play selected video.